# LinkedIn large video file upload

Tags: linkedin-api

I try to upload large video file by using multipart method but when I try to complete the upload I always get `Multipart upload metadata deserialization failure error`

```
{'message': 'com.linkedin.vector.utils.logic.LogicLayerInvalidException: Multipart upload metadata deserialization failure', 'status': 400}
```

Anyone have any idea to fix it?

I'm using python requests library.

Answer (score 1):

[Compress the video](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38380) before uploading, e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4`

You can use a python ffmpeg wrapper to do this programmatically. For example, with [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python):

```py
import ffmpeg
ffmpeg.input('input.mp4').output('output.mp4', vcodec='libx265', crf='28').run()
```